# Most of the citations are not visible and marked [0] in biblatex with biber backend

Tags: biblatex, biber, scrreprt

I noticed that most of the citations are not visible and marked [0] in `biblatex` with `biber` backend. MWE is presented below-

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber,refsection=section,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
% sentences are omitted to keep the code short
Daily living \cite{activities2017wiki}.
Systems \cite{muramatsu2011japan}.

\chapter{Chapter 2}
Dynamic Movement Primitives \cite{ijspeert2003learning}.
Calibration \cite{umeyama1991least} to align the frames.

\section{Section 1}
The controller can be \cite{ijspeert2013dynamical}.

\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={All References}]

\clearpage
\section*{\Huge Category Wise}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Category Wise}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true,keyword={journal},title={Journal Only}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true,keyword={conference},title={Conference Only}]
\end{document}
```

The `references.bib` file is shown below-

```
@MISC{activities2017wiki,
  TITLE = {{Activities of Daily Living}},
  URL   = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activities_of_daily_living},
  DATE  = {2017},
  NOTE  = {Accessed: 2017-07-30},
}

@ARTICLE{muramatsu2011japan,
  AUTHOR       = {Muramatsu, Naoko and Akiyama, Hiroko},
  TITLE        = {{Japan: super-aging society preparing for the future}},
  JOURNALTITLE = {The Gerontologist},
  PUBLISHER    = {Oxford University Press},
  DATE         = {2011},
  NUMBER       = {4},
  PAGES        = {425--432},
  VOLUME       = {51},
  KEYWORDS     = {journal},
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{ijspeert2003learning,
  AUTHOR    = {Ijspeert, AJ and Nakanishi, Jun and Schaal, Stefan},
  TITLE     = {{Learning control policies for movement imitation and movement recognition}},
  BOOKTITLE = {Neural information processing system},
  DATE      = {2003},
  PAGES     = {1547--1554},
  VOLUME    = {15},
  KEYWORDS  = {conference},
}

@ARTICLE{ijspeert2013dynamical,
  AUTHOR       = {Ijspeert, Auke Jan and Nakanishi, Jun and Hoffmann, Heiko and Pastor, Peter and Schaal, Stefan},
  TITLE        = {{Dynamical movement primitives: learning attractor models for motor behaviors}},
  JOURNALTITLE = {Neural computation},
  PUBLISHER    = {MIT Press},
  DATE         = {2013},
  NUMBER       = {2},
  PAGES        = {328--373},
  VOLUME       = {25},
  KEYWORDS     = {journal},
}

@ARTICLE{umeyama1991least,
  AUTHOR       = {Umeyama, Shinji},
  TITLE        = {{Least-squares estimation of transformation parameters between two point patterns}},
  JOURNALTITLE = {IEEE Transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence},
  PUBLISHER    = {IEEE},
  DATE         = {1991},
  NUMBER       = {4},
  PAGES        = {376--380},
  VOLUME       = {13},
  KEYWORDS     = {journal},
}
```

Please see below for generated PDF-

[image]

**We can notice the following problems-**

1. Almost all (except 1) of the citations are marked [0] in all chapters.
2. Most of the citations are not visible in 'All References'

While compiling, I see the following messages in the terminal-

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{cite.0@ijspeert2003learning} has been referenced bu
t does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{cite.0@muramatsu2011japan} has been referenced but 
does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{cite.0@activities2017wiki} has been referenced but 
does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

I am using TeX Live 2020. Any workaround, please?

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle: `latex -> biber -> latex (twice)` on the main file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE contains the option

```
refsection=section,
```

That means that every call to `\section` (or `\section*`) in your document starts a new `refsection`. `refsection`s form completely independent parts of the document as far as citations and the bibliography are concerned. What is cited and appears in the bibliography in one `refsection` need not appear in the bibliography of another `refsection`.

In your document that setup essentially reduces to

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Daily living \cite{activities2017wiki}.
Systems \cite{muramatsu2011japan}.

\chapter{Chapter 2}
Dynamic Movement Primitives \cite{ijspeert2003learning}.
Calibration \cite{umeyama1991least} to align the frames.

%---------------------------------------------------
% new refsection
\newrefsection
\section{Section 1}
The controller can be \cite{ijspeert2013dynamical}.

\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={All References}]
```

The citations in the first half are completely independent of the citations in the second half. Indeed, there is no bibliography for the citations in the first half, which in this setup (`defernumbers=true,`) means that they don't even get numbers (they end up being [0]). Only `ijspeert2013dynamical` gets a number because it has a correponding bibliography entry.

In the setting of your MWE it appears you don't want an automatic `refsection=section,`.
You can issue `\newrefsection` manually wherever you want.
Something like the following appears more appropriate

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{activities2017wiki,
  TITLE   = {Activities of Daily Living},
  URL     = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activities_of_daily_living},
  DATE    = {2017},
  urldate = {2017-07-30},
}
@ARTICLE{muramatsu2011japan,
  AUTHOR       = {Muramatsu, Naoko and Akiyama, Hiroko},
  TITLE        = {Japan: Super-aging Society Preparing for the Future},
  JOURNALTITLE = {The Gerontologist},
  PUBLISHER    = {Oxford University Press},
  DATE         = {2011},
  NUMBER       = {4},
  PAGES        = {425--432},
  VOLUME       = {51},
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{ijspeert2003learning,
  AUTHOR    = {Ijspeert, A. J. and Nakanishi, Jun and Schaal, Stefan},
  TITLE     = {Learning Control Policies for Movement Imitation
               and Movement Recognition},
  BOOKTITLE = {Neural information processing system},
  DATE      = {2003},
  PAGES     = {1547--1554},
  VOLUME    = {15},
}
@ARTICLE{ijspeert2013dynamical,
  AUTHOR       = {Ijspeert, Auke Jan and Nakanishi, Jun and Hoffmann, Heiko
                  and Pastor, Peter and Schaal, Stefan},
  TITLE        = {Dynamical Movement Primitives:
                  Learning Attractor Models for Motor Behaviors},
  JOURNALTITLE = {Neural computation},
  PUBLISHER    = {MIT Press},
  DATE         = {2013},
  NUMBER       = {2},
  PAGES        = {328--373},
  VOLUME       = {25},
}
@ARTICLE{umeyama1991least,
  AUTHOR       = {Umeyama, Shinji},
  TITLE        = {Least-squares Estimation of Transformation Parameters
                  Between Two Point Patterns},
  JOURNALTITLE = {IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis
                  and Machine Intelligence},
  DATE         = {1991},
  NUMBER       = {4},
  PAGES        = {376--380},
  VOLUME       = {13},
  KEYWORDS     = {journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
Daily living \cite{activities2017wiki}.
Systems \cite{muramatsu2011japan}.

\chapter{Chapter 2}
Dynamic Movement Primitives \cite{ijspeert2003learning}.
Calibration \cite{umeyama1991least} to align the frames.

\section{Section 1}
The controller can be \cite{ijspeert2013dynamical}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={All References}]

\newrefsection % or maybe not?
\addchap{Category Wise}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, resetnumbers=true,
                   type=article, title={Journal Only}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, resetnumbers=true,
                   type=inproceedings, title={Conference Only}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Complete bibliography with five entrues]

Note how we can filter the bibliography by `type` instead of `keyword`.

Comment: It works like a charm. This is what I was looking for. Furthermore, the `\addchap` command is great. Thank you very much!